# How can I avoid overwriting a file which has all the print result in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, networking, network-programming

I'm running a Python script to run commands on switches. It's logging the switch running those commands and printing this output in a file.

Now I will make changes on my file and rerun it. Now the results that are generated will be saved in the same location as the previous file. I don't want to overwrite the previous file. Instead, I want to create another file and do a diff on both files.
Also, the script should create another file if there is another file with the same name in the directory of the outputted file(s).
I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Use a new output filename each time the program runs.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Or, if you know running the program again is going to overwrite a file, just copy or move the file to a different name first.

Comment: what will be the point of scripting then

Comment: @JohnGordon I am writing to file like 

/*
with open(f"{base_directory}/{self.logfile_name}" , "w") as f:
            for device_name, cli_output in self.cli_output.items():
                f.write("\r\n\r\n")
                f.write("*" * 50 + device_name + "*" * 50 + "\r\n" )
                f.write(cli_output)
*/
How can I have a new filename each time?

Answer (score 0):

`import os`

I'm assuming you're writing to the "current working directory." In this case I will be using os.getcwd() as the output location.

Anyway you can use `os.listdir(os.getcwd())` to get the names of all of the files in the folder you're writing to. Then just iterate through like this:

```
filename = "75077597_"
suffix = ".txt" 
files = os.listdir() # if there's a specific path, add it as an argument
for number in range (40000): 
    if not (filename + str(number) + suffix) in files: 
        # write file using the filename: (filename + str(number) + suffix)
        break
```

Comment: I think your logic is backwards -- if that filename exists, you would want the loop to keep going and pick a new number, yes?

Comment: Also, `os.listdir()` works on the current directory by default.  There's no need for `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Also also, you're calling `os.listdir()` once per number, which is quite wasteful.

Comment: fixed the first by adding a `not`. fixed second and third with line 3